# iperf gives wrong output

Tags: linux, networking

I ran iperf on Windows and Linux machine to check bandwidth speed.

Windows bandwidht speed, I explicitly set to 10Mbps/Full and Linux's BW speed is 100Mbps/Full.

Following is the strange output I got:
Client Side ( Linux Box ):

```
iperf -c 192.168.1.72 -r
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
Client connecting to 192.168.1.72, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 16.0 KByte (default)
[  5] local 192.168.1.70 port 52358 connected with 192.168.1.72 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]  0.0-10.2 sec  11.6 MBytes  **9.60 Mbits/sec**
[  4] local 192.168.1.70 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.72 port 1334
[  4]  0.0-10.1 sec  11.2 MBytes  **9.34 Mbits/sec**
```

And on server side ( Windows Box ):

```
iperf.exe -s
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 64.0 KByte (default)
[  4] local 192.168.1.72 port 5001 connected to 192.168.1.70 port 52358
[ ID] Interval Transfer Bandwidth
[  4] 0.0-10.4 sec 11.6 MBytes **9.40 Mbits/sec**
Client connecting to 192.168.1.70 port 5001
TCP window size: 64.0 KByte (default)
[  4] local 192.168.1.72 port 1334 connected with 192.168.1.70 port 5001
Waiting for server threads to complete. Interrupt again to force quit.
[  4] 0.0-10.1 sec 11.2 MBytes **9.35 Mbits/sec**
```

I don't understand this difference between output

Comment: Could you elaborate on what specific concern you have?

Comment: If the bandwidth is between Linux-windows is 100Mbps, then why it is showing just ~9Mbits. Output need to be around 90+Mbps

Comment: If your windows machine is at 10/full how could it possibly handle 90Mbps?

Comment: But If I do vice versa, means making windows as client and Linux as server, then still I am getting the same result

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing NIC transmit speed (100M vs 10M) and [throughput](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throughput#Maximum_sustained_throughput).  `iperf` measures [throughput](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throughput#Maximum_sustained_throughput).

I'm going on the assumption you have a network set up like this:

```
Windows---------[Ethernet Switch]-----------Linux
       10M/full                    100M/full
```

It does not matter whether your server or client is the 100M side.  TCP throughput is constrained by the *lowest* bandwidth in the path, which means that you cannot exceed 10Mbps in this topology.

If you want more [throughput](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throughput#Maximum_sustained_throughput), ensure that windows links up at 100M.

Comment: Look like, there was some confusion. Thnx for clearing the thing

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting Mbits output opposed to Mbytes output that you expect. You can use the `--format` or `-f` switch to change the output format.

Use these client commands:

For KBytes:
`iperf -f K -c 192.168.1.72 -r`

For MBytes:
`iperf -f M -c 192.168.1.72 -r`

For more info `man iperf`

Comment: If the bandwidth is between Linux-windows is 100Mbps, then why it is showing just ~9Mbits ???